# Transfer of Domain When Hosting Site No Longer Exists

Tags: domain-transfer

I've a question about transferring a domain onto another hosting provider. I've bought a domain from managedphp.com with registrar from Enom, Inc.

I would like to get hosting from another provider and keep the same domain name--the problem is the old provider does not exist anymore and there is no way to provide credentials. On top of that when I whois the domain it says status *locked*.

How to I claim ownership of the domain name if the hosting provider where I had my credentials is down?

Comment: I'd contact ENOM support and ask about the situation, I had a similar thing happen with a domain a few years back. The ISP was using Joker to register their domains for clients and Joker were more than happy to bring the domain back under my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the old hosting company offered 1 free domain with your hosting account and they have gone out of business?

I would look for a phone number and email to the old hosting provider, check their whois records and Google to find contact information. If they were the ones who registered the domain they are the owners. You would need to ask them to transfer it to a registrar where you have an account.

There is a discussion about this company here with other customers facing the same problems
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1064802

Comment: thanks a lot. one last question is--the domain expires next month so once it does i can buy it again with a new hosting company am i correct?

Comment: @lemonpole you can Backorder the domain so you will get it as soon as it's deleted. After domains expire they go into a redemption period giving owners a chance to pay for the domain and not lose it. After the redemption period is pending delete, and finally deleted. That takes a few weeks to a few months.

Comment: and to backorder i would then contact the registrar, that being enom in this case right?

Comment: You can backorder using GoDaddy if you want, it doesn't have to be enom.